# Export DB2 table filter with timestamp column SQL error "-180"

Tags: timestamp, db2, export

I am trying to export data from table in which filter is added on Timestamp column, but its returning with SQL error "-180" SQLSTATE=22007.

```
EXPORT TO "e:\temp\SPO_DPDN_DET.csv" OF DEL MODIFIED BY coldel, codepage=1208 MESSAGES "e:\temp\SPO_DPDN_DET.log"
select * from mcare.SPO_DPDN_DET001 where SP_CODE in('919097','919025') AND APPR_TIME BETWEEN '11.07.2017' and '24.07.2017';
```

`APPR_TIME` is a `Timestamp` column. I'm getting this error:

> SQL3104N  The Export utility is beginning to export data to file "e:\temp\SPO_DPDN_DET.csv".
>
> SQL3015N  An SQL error "-180" occurred during processing.
>
> SQL0180N  The syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is incorrect. SQLSTATE=22007
>
> SQL3105N  The Export utility has finished exporting "0" rows.

Comment: Which part of the error message seems unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your between doesnt work on timestamp, like mao explain you, you can convert to date like this too :

```
select * from mcare.SPO_DPDN_DET001 
where SP_CODE in ('919097','919025') 
AND date(APPR_TIME) BETWEEN '2017-07-11' and '2017-07-24';
```

Answer (score 2):

If the datatype of APPR_TIME is  "timestamp" then use a valid timestamp literal, else if it is datatype "date" then use a valid date literal.

Easier to use ISO format literals, example for timestamp literal is '2017-07-11-00.00.00.000000', or for a date it is '2017-07-11'  (for July 11, i.e. yyyy-mm-dd format).